# I want to print selected records from mysql to printer using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

My question is how can i make hard copy of selected records from mysql using php without printing the whole page?

For example: Look at the page http://tulipindia.biz/associate_report.php

Here i want to print only the records selected through checkbox.

How i can do this?

And also i want to know how can i select the records using the checkbox element in form?.

I will be very if someone help me in this matter

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) and hide the unwanted page elements. The print stylesheet is only used when the browser tries to print a page. This gives you great control over what gets printed and what doesn't.